# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token new

Tags: javascript

Задумал функцию inHTML, которая будет "дописывать" HTML код. 
Планировал её использовать как `document.getElementById('text').inHTML('<p>HelloWorld</p>');`

Код получился такой:

```
function inHTML(new) {
    innerHTML = innerHTML + new;
}
```

Ничего не сработало, случилась ошибка:

> `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token new`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`new` зарезервированное слово, кстати - не только в JS. Перепишите функцию, например так:

```
 function inHTML(newHtml) {
   innerHTML += newHtml;
   // но, забегая на перед, смысла в ней нет :)
   // и сейчас у вас будет ошибка вида
   // Object #<HTMLSomeTagElement> has no method inHTML
 }
```

Comment: А вот список всех зарезервированных слов в js http://goo.gl/ZlLWt